# Azure apps service: Express application running on port 443 without changing process.env.PORT

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed node.js(express) web application using azure pipelines. The application listens on port specified by
`server.listen(process.env.PORT ||3000);`
When logging process.env.PORT using a route, it displays 8080 but the app is running on port 443. How does this happen? The application is not accessible on port 8080.

Comment: How you are accessing the url ? access your site with the url https://myapp.azurewebsites.net.

Comment: I do use the url. My problem being I don't understand what's happening. Server should by listening either on port 8080 or port 3000. It seems to somehow run on port 443 and port 80.

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible to access apps hosted by Azure Apps Services via port 80 or 443.

Azure forwards requests to the internal port specified by your docker configuration.

It is not possible to publicly access your app through any other port.